# Azure mysql connection redirection changes encoding

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mysql-database

I use a php app that connects to mysql in Azure. I use utf8mb4 as encoding and utf8mb4_unicode_ci as collation.

Everything works as usual when I connect to Mysql without connection forwarding.
When I enable connection forwarding in the php.ini as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-redirection) I get errors about malformed UTF-8 characters when processing the results of database queries. Could it be possible that connection forwarding changes the encoding? If yes, can I disable it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that's a [Bug](https://github.com/microsoft/mysqlnd_azure/issues/26) when using the lib with PDO.
The charset in the connection string is simply ignored.

It can be worked around by using `SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci` as `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND`

Comment: No only for PDO, mysqli will hit the issue as well. You can also mitigate it by init_connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'